# How to change the bottom gesture bar background color on Android with React Native Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm using react native with expo, and in android, there is a white stripe behind the gesture bar.
How can I make it so that it has the same background color as the app?

[gesture bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2bal.jpg)

Solutions I tried to no success:

```
"androidNavigationBar": {
    "visible": "sticky-immersive"
}
```

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the problem was that I was trying to put the "androidNavigationBar" config INSIDE the "android" config and that was wrong, but anyway, seems like the correct way to do it is not use app.json at all -

https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/android-navigation-bar-visible-deprecated.md

Comment: Hi Tom, Welcome to Stack overflow While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.